# Editing a txt file in Python to edit the formatting and then create new txt file

Tags: python, scripting, formatting

and thank you for taking the time to read this post. This is literally my first time trying to use Python so bare with me.

My Target／Goal: Edit the original text file (Original .txt file) so that for every domain listed an "OR" is added in between them (below target formatting image). Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have been able to google the information to open and read the txt file, however, I am not sure how to do the formatting part.

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfKMR.png)

[Original .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGlcX.png)

[Target formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0h9r.png)

Comment: Simply replace `"\n"` with `" OR "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a couple lines as:

```
with open(my_file) as fd:
    result = fd.read().replace("\n", " OR ")
```

You could then write this to another file with:

```
with open(formatted_file, "w") as fd:
     fd.write(result)
```

Comment: you can use single `with` though `with open(my_file) as inp, open(formatted_file, "w") as outp:`

Comment: Thanks， I can't tell you how much time this will save me in my work!

Comment: @poLi - cool, that's what peers are for!

Answer (score 0):

something you could do is the following

```py
import re


# This opens the file in read mode
with open('Original.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Read the contents of the file
    contents = file.read()

# Seems that your original file has line breaks to each domain so
# you could replace it with the word "OR" using a regular expression
contents = re.sub(r'\n+', ' OR ', contents)

# Then you should open the file in write mode
with open('Original.txt', 'w') as file:
    # and finally write the modified contents to the file
    file.write(contents)
```

a suggestion is, maybe you want to try first writing in a different file to see if you are happy with the results (or do a copy of `Original.txt` just in case)

```py
with open('AnotherOriginal.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(contents)
```